# XUnit ClassFixture working properly but how?

Tags: .net, fixtures, xunit.net

I have a question about the xUnit working mechanism.

I observe some weird situations for My CollectionDefinitions which we use for Unit Tests. For example, I don't know how the example below is working. Normally, I expected some cycle-error-thing but somehow it works properly and does not throw any error.

```
    [CollectionDefinition(nameof(ContainerDefinition))]
public class ContainerDefinition : ICollectionFixture<MongoDbContainer>, ICollectionFixture<RedisContainer>,IClassFixture<Setup>
{
}
```

My intention here that The Container Definition Should create Mongo Container and Redis Container and also should initialize data to created databases with the Setup file.

```
[Collection(nameof(ContainerDefinition))]
public class Setup:IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly MongoDbContainer _container;
    private readonly RedisContainer _redisContainer;
    
    public Setup(MongoDbContainer container, RedisContainer redisContainer)
    {
        _container = container;
        _redisContainer = redisContainer;
    }
 public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
    }
}
```

I was expecting the cycyle-error-thing here because I set, the Setup class as a ClassFixture  in the ContainerDefiniton and call the ContainerDefinition from the inside of the Setup. Weirdly, It is working when I define Setup Class as a ClassFixture. But it throws an error when I changed it to CollectionFixture. And another behavior that I couldn't understand is how redisContainer and mongoContainer are ready when the Setup constructor is called. The reason that confused me is that my expectation was getting a null exception from the constructor call.